# Bound target not updating when button pressed to change value

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have some code which uses a form. The form is bound to my class, `FormData`. I have binding working well and updating my `formData` (local instance), but when I try to change the value of one of the variables in `formData` on button click/LostFocus trigger, it doesn't update.

Here's my relevant XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="friendly_name_textBox" 
                     Style="{StaticResource TextErrorStyle}"
                     Text="{Binding 
                PrimaryUserName,
                Mode=TwoWay,
                ValidatesOnExceptions=True,
                ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                     Margin="0,75,0,0" 
                     TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                     Width="120"/>`
```

The button trigger (which does get run):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        formData.PrimaryUserName = "TEST";
    }
```

And my `FormData` code:

```
public string PrimaryUserName
    {
        get
        {
            return primaryUserNameValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if(primaryUserNameValue != value)
            {
                primaryUserNameValue = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface) interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event in your `formData` class:

```
public class formData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string primaryUserNameValue;
    public string PrimaryUserName
    {
        get
        {
            return primaryUserNameValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (primaryUserNameValue != value)
            {
                primaryUserNameValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was implementing the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface and didn't realize I needed `INotifyPropertyChanged`. It works well now.

Answer (score -1):

Your Class needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, so that the target knows if the source property changes:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification
It's really easy, please have a look at the documentation and adjust your code accordingly. Your Property would have to look like this:

```
public string PrimaryUserName
{
    get
    {
        return primaryUserNameValue;
    }
    set
    {
        if(primaryUserNameValue != value)
        {
            primaryUserNameValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PrimaryUserName");
        }
    }
}
```

But you also need the event and onPropertyChanged function to make it work.
Happy Coding!